# dividing richtextbox lines - console app into windows forms

Tags: c#, regex, forms, richtextbox

I made a program in console that splits two texts from a file in every line that are divided with **":"**, and checks if they meet the requirements. Every line in the file has a syntax **"xxxxx:xxxxx"**.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            string textone, texttwo, filename;  
            Regex reg = new Regex("/W");//svi characteri osim A-Z,a-z,0-9  
            Regex numb = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");  
            Regex numbek = new Regex("[0-9]");  
            Regex donjacrta = new Regex("_");  
            filename = Console.ReadLine();//should load richtextbox instead  
            string[] linije = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);  
            for (int i = 0; i < linije.Length; i++)    
            {  
                string trenutni = linije[i];  
                int indexx = trenutni.IndexOf(':');  
                textone = trenutni.Substring(0, indexx);  
                texttwo = trenutni.Substring((indexx + 1), (trenutni.Length) - (indexx + 1));  
                if (textone.Length < 3 || textone.Length > 25 || reg.IsMatch(textone) || donjacrta.IsMatch(textone) || !numb.IsMatch(textone) || !numbek.IsMatch(textone))  
                {  
                    continue;  
                }  
                else if (texttwo.Length < 3 || texttwo.Length > 30 )  
                {  
                    continue;  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(textone + ":" + texttwo);  
                }  
            }  
             }
                        }
                 }
```

(when i try to format the code here it deletes/hides some of the code, dont know why)

In my WindowsForms, I first load the file into a RichTextBox. From there i need to connect it somehow and make it either:

1. clear the whole richtextbox and start typing only the valid lines
2. delete the invalid lines.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

It took me some time to understand what you're trying to do and what you want, but, I think I found your solution. You can pretty much remove all the code you've written and replace it with a single regular expression.

What I believe you are trying to do:

- Match strings that are split by `:` (i.e. `xxxxx:xxxxx` - where `x` is defined below) and each string consumes a single row in a text file
- Ensure both sections (before and after the colon `:`) match `a-zA-Z0-9` ONLY (no other character)
- Ensure the first section is between 3 and 25 characters
- Ensure the second section is between 3 and 30 characters

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ZzxCM0/2)

```
^([a-zA-Z\d]{3,25}):([a-zA-Z\d]{3,30})$
```

For a sample C# program, you can use the following. Obviously, you would replace the logic to pull from a text file rather than a string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z\d]{3,25}):([a-zA-Z\d]{3,30})$";
        string input = @"xxxxx:xxxxx
1adfasfdfasdfsdfsfsfssfsd:1asfdsfsdfsafsdfsadfdfsdfadf2s
sfsd12321:12sfs3123
@342fdfasd:1dsadafdsfs";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
xxxxx:xxxxx
1adfasfdfasdfsdfsfsfssfsd:1asfdsfsdfsafsdfsadfdfsdfadf2s
sfsd12321:12sfs3123
@342fdfasd:1dsadafdsfs
```

#### Output

The below are matched strings. Each string

- Full match: `xxxxx:xxxxx`

  - Group 1: `xxxxx`
  - Group 2: `xxxxx`
- Full match: `1adfasfdfasdfsdfsfsfssfsd:1asfdsfsdfsafsdfsadfdfsdfadf2s`

  - Group 1: `1adfasfdfasdfsdfsfsfssfsd`
  - Group 2: `1asfdsfsdfsafsdfsadfdfsdfadf2s`
- Full match: `sfsd12321:12sfs3123`

  - Group 1: `sfsd12321`

    ### - Group 2: `12sfs3123`

### Explanation

- Assert position at the beginning of the line
- Match and capture into group 1: Any character in the set `a-zA-Z\d` between 3 and 25 times
- Match a colon `:`
- Match and capture into group 2: Any character in the set `a-zA-Z\d` between 3 and 30 times
- Assert position at the end of the line